# .hgignore with auto generated files

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

When running build in my application, the components generate various minified CSS and JS files with names such as `site.min.dsua879d8s9h8923.js.` I am trying to permanently ignore those files using `.hgignore` in Mercurial.

I am usign the glob syntac and have tried the following:

```
site.min.*.js 
site.min.*
*.site.min.*
```

and nothing seems to work - on each commit the TortoiseHG still picks up those autogenerated files and marks them as being `Added`.

what syntax will work for excluding those files?

Answer (score 0):

The following should ignore `site.min.dsua879d8s9h8923.js.`  (not sure if you trailing period is intended):

```
# mercurial ignore file
syntax:glob
glob:*site.min.*.js*
```

Normally thg doesn't automatically add files. (Not the way I use it anyway - using thg workbench). Do you perhaps have custom hooks for automatically adding files?